# PHP Session cookie randomly being nonsecure, fails to replace secure cookie, 90% all Firefox users afflicted

Tags: php, session, firefox, gecko

## Catalyst:

[Gecko Bug 1617361](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1617361) is a severe cookie-related bug where Gecko browsers randomly refuse to send the HTTP `Cookie` header (either extremely difficult to reproduce or (for the layman) extremely difficult to escape (just clear cookies)). It was later revealed that Gecko *does not report an error* where nonsecure cookies were not able to overwrite secure cookies. However after changing the session cookie name from `session`  to `session2` and setting all the security/domain settings to `FALSE` Gecko is *still refusing to send the HTTP Cookie header*. This bug is severe enough that it afflicts 90% of all people's Gecko browsers effectively preventing them from loading websites powered by my platform. As someone fundamentally against monopolies I need to address this on all fronts.

## Which Bugs are Which?

- Gecko Bug 1617361 is when Gecko randomly chooses to *not* set the HTTP `Cookie` header.
- Gecko Bug 1623284 (below) is about Gecko not bothering to mention that the session cookie was not acceptable because it's not secure and the current one *is secure*.
- This bug is about figuring out how my PHP code could generate the session cookie *without the security/domain/whatever flags*.

## Question:

How would my PHP code below fail to set the `session` cookie as secure in any context of a request (on live (or "production") servers) and how would I rewrite the code to ensure that the session cookie is not only secure when it is set though *always* secure when it is reinitialized for subsequent page requests?

## Error Message

The following is the error *this post* is directly about. This error message is *only generated when in **Firefox*** you go to `about:networking#logging`, set `cookie:5` to "Current Load Modules" (comma delimiter) and log while the issue occurs hence the difficulty and frustration of not just one though multiple bugs. Here is the error message it generates:

> W/cookie rejected because cookie can't save because older cookie is secure cookie but newer cookie is non-secure cookie

## Details:

While there are two bugs relevant to this post the bug I'm trying to address is when my *PHP code resumes the session but does not make the session cookie secure*. In an attempt to address the issue for the original catalyst bug my server now uses `setcookie('session2',session_id(),time()+3600,'/',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], FALSE, FALSE);` until both that bug and my own PHP code are all properly working.

- I am happy to update the question and provide any other relevant code.
- The domain in question is linked in my profile though as I mentioned I've set the session cookie to nonsecure for now.
- This bug seems to occur in both local/WAMP and live/LAMP environments.

## Verification Requirements for Acceptable Answer

- I need to be able to reproduce the occurrence of the session cookie when it is refusing to be sent as secure (the domain in my profile is a good example of my platform's HTTP behavior).
- I need to understand what about my code, the environment and/or any bugs in PHP itself that are causing this issue.
- I need to be able to reliably know that session cookies being sent in all instances are secure, especially since Gecko browsers *do not tell you about the error in the developer console* (posted [bug 1623284](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1623284) for that).
- I do *not* use frameworks or libraries for any of my client/server code.

Here is the original PHP code that handled sessions:

```
<?php
if (substr($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],0,1) == '/' && isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')
{
 ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
 ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);
 session_set_cookie_params(3600);
}
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite','Strict');
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
session_name('session');
session_start();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed question. I'm still not sure if I get everything correctly. My understanding: Your app sends an https cookie and subsequent request sends an http-cookie which gets blocked by the browser. Question; Is your site serving https and non-https requests at the same time OR do you perform redirects from http to https within your app?

Comment: After checking your website in your profile I've discovered 2 things which seem strange to me. 1) You are sending the cookie-headers also on some of your asset files like `.js` and `.jpeg` files. Is this your intension? 2) After the initial redirect you application sends the `session2` cookie twice inside the response with different settings. Do you include your session-script two times and/or do you initialize your session somewhere else in your app?

Comment: @ChristophKluge Hi, I'm just seeing this now. The main problem is that PHP was attempting to send a nonsecure cookie to overwrite the secure cookie. I was previously not aware of session_set_cookie_params() taking multiple parameters. The second cookie was just a placeholder to attempt to relieve the issue until I find a resolution. Thankfully I have a website that gets 95% Gecko browsers for human visitors. The cookies on assets aren't intended, I'm just using $_SESSION to get basic information to those files. The only `jpeg` is to test for `noscript` but browsers incorrectly request it.

Comment: 1) Which php version are you using? 2)Can you add any session specific options from php.ini(e.g. session.auto_start etc)? 3) Do you use a load balancer for your site? 4) Are you sure $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is set always? 5) Can you check apache error log for any errors, also enable php warnings and notices?

Comment: @JannesBotis I have access to php.ini. Apache always redirects to HTTPS (unless you want to go hunt down and find an instance that it somehow misses, my software always does this if Apache fails). I am *always* looking to fix issues, egotism be damned. I also always use `isset()` (I use strict mode on all aspects that I am aware of) and I have all errors and warnings set to max though if you feel there are settings less heard of please post and if I haven't come across them I'll at least happily up-vote the answer. ☺

Comment: why you check "isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'" if the user always redirects to https? Why not make all cookies secure by default.

Comment: @JannesBotis HTTPS is a PITA on localhost and I mostly only test HTTPS locally in regards to payment processors for the most part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bit tricky but I hope I have found a solution for you. I assume (1) will solve your problem. Everything else is optional and should help you to reduce some potential issues.

**1. Add your domain name to the default cookie parameters when useing samesite=Strict**

I was able to reproduce your issue with your code snippet. My Opera browser was not showing the cookie and was ignoring them completely.

Interestingly when trying a `curl` request on the CLI then the `set-cookie` header was available which started to puzzle me a lot.

If you enable `samesite=Strict` then you MUST set your domain within `session_set_cookie_params` otherwise my browser was ignoring it.

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', 'cookie-test.local');
```

was fixing the issue for me.

**2. Your site sends the "set-cookie" header twice with different settings**

```
$ curl -I -X GET https://www.jabcreations.com/ | grep set-cookie
set-cookie: session2=e633d6fcb7fb426f86b065173bc6c8ab; expires=Wed, 18-Mar-2020 20:05:21 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict
set-cookie: session2=e633d6fcb7fb426f86b065173bc6c8ab; expires=Wed, 18-Mar-2020 20:05:21 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=www.jabcreations.com
```

I was able to reproduce this with the following code. My Opera-browser also show me the error inside the specific request's header-tab. Next to the cookie you'll see small yellow "hazard" icon. In my case it displayed that I tried to use a secure cookie on a non-secure connection.

```
setcookie('session2', session_id(), time() + 3600, '/', "", false, false);
setcookie('session2', session_id(), time() + 3600, '/', "", true, true);
```

In this case I would try to identify your `session_` function usage and your `setcookie()` usage.

Since you are not using any particular framework I would give my first guess to autoloader and/or an `include` or `require` statement which is used twice inside your project.

Please let me know how you load your files inside your project.

**3. (Offtopic) Your site is sending cookies for your assets**

I'm not sure if your assets really need this but I would avoid sending cookies for your assets. I would say in most cases it's not relevant to have cookie handling on your assets. I would remove them. This will reduce the amount of potential cookie conflicts in your browser and cookie issues can be reduced to the relevant requests.

**4. (Offtopic) Minimal change to your condition**

I'm not sure if HTTPS is always lowercase or not but php's [$_SERVER documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) states:

> Set to a non-empty value if the script was queried through the HTTPS protocol.
>   Note: Note that when using ISAPI with IIS, the value will be **off** if the request was not made through the HTTPS protocol.

According to this I would change the condition to:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) !== 'off') {
   // ssl mode..
}
```

Comment: I have revised the `session_set_cookie_params()` part of the code with *all* of the parameters and restored the original session method. Unfortunately this takes some time to see how the issue plays out with people visiting the sites, specifically Fixed Firefox as it takes a few hours to get enough visits to determine how the code is working out for people. While waiting I'm going through the rest of the post. It's fairly detailed and this issue is very illusive and frustrating. It's also where I'm pouring mot of my attention currently until I see stability in the human visitors logs.

Comment: I have people attempting to help me at Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/flf7at/help_prevent_a_browser_monopoly_easy_help_to_keep/ and I still feel I'm missing something somewhere. `session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], TRUE, TRUE); session_name('session'); session_start();` is what I'm testing now.

Comment: Better try `HTTP_HOST` in the first place, fallback to `SERVER_NAME` and lastly use `SERVER_HOST` unless the other values are not set/empty. Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php - Do you have a way how you can reproduce you issue all the time? I will try later some requests with firefox.

Comment: So I noticed in Firefox 74 Beta that (with everything working as desired) that my server was NOT sending the Cookie (or set-cookie?) header at all for the *server response* and everything was still working. Does the session cookie need only be set once and then it works so long as the client only sends it per request? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=9134662

Comment: I've caught PHP not setting the security parameters - that in conjunction with a cookie that is already secure it is thus being rejected so the question begs - why is PHP refusing to obey it's own parameters? Now I'll have to manually construct the cookie via `header()`.

Comment: I had to move `session_set_cookie_params()` outside of the file where the session was being started - this makes zero sense though now the server is *always* properly specifying the cookie. I don't have a ton of confirmation for browsers yet though I'm filing this one under good enough. I wouldn't have even considered looking at that declaration without your post, thank you.

Comment: @John glad I could help :) Let me try to answ. your questions: `session_set_cookie_params` will have always precedence over your system defaults (php.ini, fpm-pool directives, etc..). In my understanding this is to support custom behavior depending on each request. (reverse proxies, shared webhosters, etc..). Let's say you are a website builder where you don't know the `Host` upfront. In this case I'm validating those first, before reading/setting cookies with the domain name. To avoid setting this in your code, you can set those also in your php.ini or php-fpm pool config already.

Comment: As far as I understand was the other question about: `cookie` and `set-cookie`-headers, right? So `set-cookie`-headers are performed and sent by your server to the browser. Always when php has a running session (or you have custom handling). On the other hand `cookie`-headers are sent by the browser to your server in respect of YOUR cookie settings (path, hosts, secure, samesite, ..). In simple words: The browser protects your website by not sending those cookies to your server.

Comment: So in theory only your session based files should sent cookies and not your assets. I was quite puzzled and asking myself if apache is setting the set-cookie headers OR if you send the assets through php? Anyway. The browser will always send all matching cookies. This behavior is independently if it's a css, an image, javascript or php.

Comment: I did prevent session cookies from being sent from assets. There were still a few people encountering the issue after the fix though fewer. I found your cURL command useful, Firefox is terrible at reporting information on cookies. There may still be an issue though I will chalk this one up to PHP not properly setting the session cookie.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210061/discussion-between-christoph-kluge-and-john).

Comment: I have a tab open for the chat unless there is some id for the conversation that changes? I'll leave the tab open. I'm working on a tutorial for the few still effected on how to create a network log.

Comment: I've started logging *both* request and response headers. I posted this for starters and will post a table of someone's requests that had trouble on Bugzilla if you're still interested? This issue is no afflicting Chrome users. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60824059/validity-of-http-set-cookie-header

Answer (score 2):

This issue very similar to I had once.
A problem was cookies does not save as secured and when they are already presents as secured unable to rewrite in some random case.

I figured it out that It was happened before I redirect the user.
In further investigating shown to me that the problem is newer browsers does not allows secure cookies without HTTPS connection and since I make PHP Session before I redirect the users in  URL, the problem occured.

You can check the theory above easily and also you can reproduce if you wish.
I hope that helps at least you can exclude.

Comment: PHP was not obeying `session_set_cookie_params()` until I moved it out of the file that declares the session - makes no sense. It wasn't setting the flags properly and Firefox doesn't bother to mention errors relating to cookies.